# Eclipse: Imports not being recognized

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, import, package

I'm using in my Eclipse (Java EE edition) project some classes, like the `ServletConfig`, for example. If I just add some code with an object of this class without importing it, and click on the error sign (where should appear the import option), it only shows the option to create a class with that name. And if I import it anyway:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
```

It points an error and shows me the option to `create the class 'ServletConfig' in packgae 'javax.servler'`. It was working on another computer with Windows 7. The one I'm using is Windows 8.1.

Help!

Comment: Sounds like `javax-servlet.jar` is not in your CLASSPATH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if your project isn't configure as a *web project* but rather as a plain Java project. Usually, you would do it when you create a project. You'd select *File* / *New* / *Dynamic Web Project*.

If you haven't done so, you should be able the fix the configuration. In the project settings, go to *Project Facets* and check *Dynamic Web Module*.

[image]

If I'm not mistaken, you'll need to set up a web server runtime environment as well. First go to Eclipse's preferences and select *Server* / *Runtime Environments*. If the list is empty, add one.

[image]

Then go to the project settings again and make sure there is a targeted runtime selected:

[image]

If everything goes ok, the project explorer will show all the web server jars in *Java Resources* / *Libraries* / *Apache Tomcat v7.0* (or whatever your environment is called). One of the jars is servlet-api.jar and contains the classes you're looking for.

Comment: Dude, I  love you. I had already done those things, but I went to "Targeted runtimes" and discovered that there were 2 different versions of Tomcat there, and the wrong one was checked. You helped me with this one and thousands os problems that were happening and I was almost giving up solving. Really, thanks.